# Can't access methods in DLL

Tags: vb.net, oop

Using asp.net/vb.net. Created a solution with 2 projects, "MainProject" and "MyCommonStuff". The 2nd project ("MyCommonStuff") is really a common utilities class, the resulting dll I hope to use for other projects as well.

MyCommonStuff is defined very simply....

```
Public Class MyCommonStuff Stuff
    Public Shared Function GetInfo() as string
         :
         :
    End Function
    Public Shared Sub Test
         :
         :
    End Sub
    :
End Class
```

In MainProject I set a reference to this MyCommonStuff project.

I want to access some of the MyCommonStuff methods in my code. But for some reason the methods are not being recognized.

For example, in a button in the MainProject I tried this....

```
dim m as new MyCommonStuff 
x = m.GetInfo()
```

Intellisense doesn't pick up any of the subs/functions for m. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that you've made your methods static ("Shared" in VB).  You need to *either* remove the `Shared` keywords:

```
Public Function GetInfo() As String
     ':
     ':
End Function

Public Sub Test()
     ':
     ':
End Sub
```

or keep the `Shared` keywords and use it like this:

```
x = MyCommonStuff.GetInfo()
```

[Here is some information about `Shared` members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Most notably:

> Specifies that one or more declared programming elements are
>   associated with a class or structure at large, and not with a specific
>   instance of the class or structure.

In other words, if you want to use your methods from an *instance* of your `MyCommonStuff` class, e.g. `m` in `m.GetInfo()`, you need to leave the `Shared` keyword off.  If, on the other hand, you have a method that is common across *all* instances of your class or for which you *don't even need an instance*, you would use the `Shared` keyword and access the method like I said above, e.g. `MyCommonStuff.GetInfo()`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're importing you common stuff's namespace.

Comment: Yes I do import the namespace.