# Intellisense can't detect functions in vb.net created dll

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, dll

fairly simple answer I would think but I can't seem to find a direct answer. I can see plenty around the subject but nothing addressing this particuarly (see below for closest answer I could find)

I've created a .dll using vb.net and imported it to use in Excel no problem. When I `dim` and `set` an instance of this class, intellisense picks up the library and class name but from there the function/ variable or sub routine names don't show. The routines and variables compile and run totally fine but I'd like this library to be usable to others so intellisense would be extremely helpful.

Example Code in VB.net:

```
Namespace wtf
    Public Class samplerJam
        Public jjj As String
        Public Sub method1()
            jjj = "Hello"
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Am I missing something really simple?

(found [this answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162148/cant-access-methods-in-dll) but according to that set up I should be able see my subs / functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit late to the party, but I stumbled across this question while trying to address something similar in VB.NET so hopefully this may help you / someone in the future.

## Intellisense

In terms of addressing the intellisense aspect, your original answer will work. However my method involves using a GUID.

Let's say I have a class called `Foo` that I want exposed to Excel/Access. I'll create an `Interface` which is implemented by `Foo` -

```
Public Interface IFoo
    Function HelloWorld() As String
End Interface

Public Class Foo
    Implements IFoo

    Public Function HelloWorld() As String Implements IFoo.HelloWorld
        Return "Hello World!"
    End Function
End Class
```

As you can see, `Foo` has a function called `HelloWorld` which is declared in the interface, which is implemented into the class.

So now, to make sure we get this in the intellisense we can add some attributes to our interface / class to expose them to Excel. My interface changes as follows -

```
<ComVisible(True)>
<Guid("2055A907-9D7A-4DC9-A46B-6E283713A5AB")>
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)>
Public Interface IFoo
    Function HelloWorld() As String
End Interface
```

And my class will be changed to -

```
<ComVisible(True)>
<Guid("2C4D41A7-235E-4F48-BE99-62118B2852A7")>
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)>
<ProgId("Foo")>
Public Class Foo
    Implements IFoo

    Public Function HelloWorld() As String Implements IFoo.HelloWorld
        Return "Hello World!"
    End Function
End Class
```

To generate a GUID you can use some simple steps in Visual Studio. Tools > Create GUID > Option 6 for `VB.NET` or 5 for `C#`.

Your DLL is now ready for use with intellisense!

## Registration on target machine

### Powershell

This process is manual, fine if you're doing it once in a blue moon / only have 1 target machine beyond your own.

You want to locate the .NET folder that corresponds with the version of .NET that you used to build your DLL. Assuming you're using at least .NET 4.0+ it will be here -

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`

You need to use Regasm to register the dll.

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
.\RegAsm.exe PathToYourDLL\DLLName.dll
```

**Please note that if your path contains spaces use "quotes" around the filepath**

### Creating an MSI

If you have a few target machines, it might be easier to create an MSI to perform the registration for you.

You can download an extension from the Microsoft Marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) and build an MSI / EXE to complete the registration for you.

There are plenty of tutorials on how to create an installation wizard using this extension, by default VS will set properties on your dll's to register them for you during the installation process

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually since asking this question I've ended up using this exact technique with the MSI approach. It works very well.

Answer (score 1):

After seiving through some C# stuff (There's not much VB.net about this subject) I found an answer, I need to prefix my class declaration with this `<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>` so:

```
Namespace wtf
    <ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)> Public Class samplerJam
        Public jjj As String
''' etc
```

Comment: @HansPassant : I've been doing some more digging since I posted and (sort of) understand the reason why it's not the best idea to use this method. I've figured out using a GUID for each class is better... but now I'm not sure how to deploy this to multiple computers using RegAsm or an installer package or what. Anyway thanks for the link.